# Using threads in java to solve a modeling interview riddle

Tags: java, algorithm, thread-safety

I was recently in a job interview for a position as Java Developer. I was given a task: To think about a good way to represent an electric circuit (such as the one in the figure below) in Java.
[image: a illustration]

A circuit is a combination of logic gates XOR, AND, OR etc.. Each gate has two input ports and an output port. Each output is connected to an input of another gate, which goes all the way to a higher gate (as in the picture). Make the system simple, no cycles are allowed (although real life circuits can have them). I was asked to think about a good way to represent this model in Java, using the following guidelines:

I am given a circuit and a list of values which should be provided to its inputs.
I need to create a model to represent the circuit in Java, i.e., I need to define classes and an API that could be used to represent the circuit.
According to the input values and how the gates are connected, I need to calculate the output that the represented circuit would produce.
I need to think about a way to represent the board, use abstract classes or interfaces, and show understanding of the model (and if needed to use pattern design).
I chose to design the system as a tree and the interviewer told me it was a good choice. Then I build those classes:
A gate:

```
public class gate_node {
    gate_node right_c,left_c;
    Oprtator op;
    int value;
    int right_v,left_v;
    public gate_node(gate_node right,gate_node left,Oprtator op){
        this.left_c=left;
        this.right_c=right;
        this.op=op;
        right_v=left_v=0;
    }
    int compute() {
        /* The following use of a static sInputCounter assumes that the static/global 
         * input array is ordered from left to right, irrespective of "depth".  */

        final int left = (null != this.left_c ?  this.left_c.compute()  :  main_class.arr[main_class.counter++]);
        final int right = (null != this.right_c ?  this.right_c.compute()  :  main_class.arr[main_class.counter++]);
        return op.calc(left, right);
    }   
}
```

abstract operator

```
public abstract class Oprtator {
        abstract int calc(int x, int y);
}
```

Or gate:

```
public class or extends Oprtator {
        public int calc(int x, int y){
            return (x|y);
        }
}
```

and gate:

```
public class and extends Oprtator {
        public int calc(int x, int y){
            return (x&y);
        }
}
```

A tree on gates:

```
public class tree {
    gate_node head;

    tree(gate_node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    void go_right() {
        head = head.right_c;
    }

    void go_left() {
        head = head.left_c;
    }


}
```

and a main class:

```
public class main_class {
    public static int arr[] = { 1, 1, 1, 0 };
    public static int counter = 0;

 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tree t = new tree(new gate_node(null, null, new and()));
        t.head.left_c = new gate_node(null, null, new and());
        t.head.right_c = new gate_node(null, null, new or());
 

 
        System.out.println(t.head.compute());
    }
}
```

In the above code, I implemented the board as a tree with its a current head (which can go down to the left/right children). Every node has 2 children (also node type), 2 entries (0/1), a value and an operator (abstract class, could be extended by OR/AND..).

I used a counter and an array to insert the values to the appropriate leafs of the tree (as mentioned in the code).

But then my intreviwer wanted me to use Threads, as in turn the code into a parallel computing, such as each thread will recive a gate (I have to decide on it) and will do an indempendet calcult which he will pass on until.. until a final value will be set.
I kinda didn't know what to do...
Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only give you a general idea since I'm not a java programmer.

First distinguish between gate and a tree node.

**Preperation**:

1) Implement each gate as a class/object. It has to have 2 attribures: input A, input B and a way to calculate result;

2) Implement a tree. Each node is a pair (`gate`, `next_node`). Root is a node with `next_node` being null. Leaves are nodes such that no other node points to it.

3) Use a shared (thread safe) queue of nodes. It is initially empty.

4) There is a fixed number (pick one, does not depend on number of gates) of threads which continuously wait for an element from the queue (unless the result is reached in which case they just quit).

**Loop**:

1) Whenever an input occures on a node put the node in a queue (at the begining inputs go to leaves). This can be simply implemented by defining `add_input` method on a gate.

2) A thread picks up a node from queue:

3.1) If one of the input is missing discard it (it will be there one more time when second input appears). Another idea is to put the node in a queue only when both inputs are there.

3.2) If both inputs are there, then calculate result and pass it to `next_node` if it is not null (and put `next_node` in the queue). If `next_node` is null, then this is your result - break the loop and finalize.

I'm saying "loop" although there is no real loop there. Threads waiting for nodes is the loop.

So basically this idea is a reverse of yours. In your idea you start with root and recursively calculate inputs. In my idea you start with leaves, calculate values and push it to higher nodes. Since no recursion is done you can easily divide jobs between threads.

I'm not sure whether this is what you're interviewer wants but that's the only solution that uses threads I can think of.

Comment: that idea looks fine and it is a good one in theroy, but i am not sure if it can be done (without overcomplexing things) in Java since I don't know if there is a Thread pool in Java and even if there was I don't think that my interviwer expect me to know about it and implenets one in a 30 min interview :)

Comment: You wouldn't need a full thread pool implementation.  Just start up one thread per CPU core and leave them running over a fixed loop.

Comment: @user1007665 Thread pool is very easy to implement. But you don't need anything fancy. Just start a thread which does (pseudocode) `while "no result": get me an element from the queue (and process it) or wait for it`. That's it. Also remember about race conditions (you need a thread safe queue).

Comment: I just read your answer again. thank you. just one more thing - you didn't say nothing on the input. the input is an array given to the user which should hold the values of the leafs. each threads should know exactly which array indexes to take for entries (which is hard cause each threads can arriave to a diffrent leaf). I use a static counter for that in my none-threads implemetnatin. how would you solve it? again, Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: see also the answer of Jukka Suomela to http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/which-algorithms-can-not-be-parallelized   :)

Answer (score 0):

the class which implements the circuit computation should implement the interface Runnable:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

To speed up computations, you may try to separate the circuit into two or more subcircuits, starting from the inputs to the last gate (the one which gives the output), so that the output will be the last gate applied to the results of these subcircuits. If these subcircuits do not overlap very much, by launching multiple threads for these subcircuits you should indeed get a speedup if you have multiple processors on your computer (if they overlap, you will do the same calculations more than once).

It makes no sense however to launch a thread for each gate, as launching the thread costs much more than calculating the output of a boolean gate.

Of course the circuit must be quite large to notice the effects (otherwise again the overhead of creating the threads will actually make the computation slower).

Comment: and how should I implements the Run() method in the tree class (which now need to implements the Runnable interface)?

Comment: inside the class which implements the computation and implements Runnable you should have state variables for the model of the circuit, the input, a reference for the class which launches the threads (call it Launcher), and a method to compute the output of the circuit. Before starting thread, populate state vars. run() calls the method which does the computation and then calls a suitable method on the Launcher state variable to notify it of the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches to this kind of problem, so this is just a suggestion:

- Have each object in your tree aware of which objects its output goes to
- Have a central object with a queue of objects that need to be updated.  Use one of the asynchronous queues in java.util.concurrent.
- Have a pool of threads (ideally one per CPU core) that pull items from the queue, reevaluate the state of the object's output, and add all the objects that depend on that output to the queue.

With a large number of threads, this scheme should be faster than the single threaded approach.  You can also increase efficiency by grouping together subsystems as objects that are always evaluated in a single threaded manner.